Homomorphic filtering for low-light image enhancement
I have to write a image processing project that uses Homomorphic filtering for low-light image enhancement following this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9088214
So basically I have to log, fft, apply homomorphic filter, ifft, exp. I tried to replicate the exact steps given but I somehow fumble at the last step.
This is the code:
def log_reflection_compute(img, variance):
    log_reflection = np.log10(img) - np.log10(cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0, 0), variance))
    return log_reflection

def log_illumination_compute(img, log_reflection):
    log_illumination = np.log10(img) - log_reflection
    return log_illumination

def homomorphic_filter(reflection, illumination, sigma, yH, yL, c=1):
    ln_reflection = np.log(reflection)
    ln_illumination = np.log(illumination)

fft_reflection = np.fft.fft2(ln_reflection, axes=(0, 1))
fft_illumination = np.fft.fft2(ln_illumination, axes=(0, 1))

fft_shift_reflection = np.fft.fftshift(fft_reflection)
fft_shift_illumination = np.fft.fftshift(fft_illumination)

rows, cols = fft_shift_reflection.shape[:2]
crow, ccol = rows // 2, cols // 2
x = np.linspace(-ccol, ccol, cols)
y = np.linspace(-crow, crow, rows)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
D = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

H = 1 - np.exp(- c *(D**2) / (2 * (sigma**2)))
H = (yH - yL) * H + yL

reflection_filtered = np.multiply(fft_shift_reflection, H)
illumination_filtered = np.multiply(fft_shift_illumination, H)

reflection_filtered = np.fft.ifftshift(reflection_filtered)
illumination_filtered = np.fft.ifftshift(illumination_filtered)

reflection_filtered = np.fft.ifft2(reflection_filtered, axes=(0, 1))
illumination_filtered = np.fft.ifft2(illumination_filtered, axes=(0, 1))

reflection_magnitude = np.abs(reflection_filtered)
illumination_magnitude = np.abs(illumination_filtered)

img_homomorphic = (np.exp(reflection_magnitude) * np.exp(illumination_magnitude)) - 1
img_homomorphic = 255 - cv2.normalize(img_homomorphic, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)

return img_homomorphic

So basically what I do not understand is why do I need to subtract 255 from the final normalized image.
    img_homomorphic = 255 - cv2.normalize(img_homomorphic, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)

Below I will show you the original, non-inverted and inverted in the previously mentioned order:



Is something wrong with my code?
Thank you!

"why do I need to subtract 255 from the final normalized image" do you understand what this does? what does it do?

Inverts the pixel values. That's why I'm saying that according to that paper this operation should not be needed. This is just the easy way to get a bright image from a dark one, but I am aware that this is NOT correct implementation.

What are yH and yL? Please provide complete code that we might run it ourselves. Why are you computing the absolute value of the output of the IFFT? Are you getting a significant imaginary component? If you are, then there’s something wrong with the kernel. If you’re not, then just discard the imaginary component and keep the real part.

Also, please remove those functions from your code that are never used. Is all the unindented code supposed to be part of the homomorphic_filter function?
